# The car has maximum power, why not maximum force?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, power

> Suppose a car is moving up an inclined plane, it experiences resistive force proportional to its mass and square of speed. First, it carries a cart of twice its mass up an inclined plane and it can have maximum speed $v$. Then, it moves up the incline without cart, and now it can have maximum speed $2v$.

I assumed that the car can exert certain maximum force $F$ and wrote the equation as follows:

Case 1(with cart): $$F= 3mgsin@ + 3kmv²$$
Case 2(without cart): $$F= mgsin@ + 4kmv²$$

The author doesn't seem to agree with me. He writes, "The car can have certain maximum power $P_{max}$ " and proceeds further to solve the problem.

Why it's maximum power and not the maximum force?

Answer (score 1):

Force is not a conserved quantity. Consider the case of a human being: by using a lever, he can arbitrarily increase his force. Likewise, with a gear system, you can increase or decrease the torque provided by a motor. And the torque delivered is related to the force on the wheel via the transmission ratio. Energy is conserved: if the engine provides 100 hp, you transmit roughly 100 hp to the car. and therefore it is more natural to use maximum power.

Ultimately, one could say that neither answer is correct. For a transmission ratio and an imposed wheel size, the manufacturer provides a curve which gives the power as a function of speed or, strictly equivalently, the torque and therefore the "force" as a function of speed. The final speed is obtained by finding the intersection of this curve with the relationship you indicate. It is entirely possible that the intersection point corresponds neither to the maximum "force" nor to the maximum power.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to all of these kinds of "why" questions is "because we observed it is true."  I like to preface an answer with that to point out that you shouldn't take our word for it.  Go out and run experiments.  Find out that the universe behaves one way or the other.  There's no philosophical reason why it couldn't be a force limited car rather than a power limited car.  But when we run real life experiments, we find that power is the limiting factor.

The preface aside, the reason why it is power limited is because of the nature of the engine itself.  The internal combustion engine is built around repeatedly mixing fuel and oxygen in a piston and then igniting it, releasing energy.  A fixed amount of energy is released in every explosion (based on how much fuel and oxygen are mixed in).  Since power is energy per unit time, increasing power means more explosions per second.

However, there are structural limits.  At some point you find that the metal making up the engine cannot handle the strain of moving faster to allow more explosions.  This defines a maximum power that the engine could provide.

There are things we can do to work around this, but then we run into other physical limits.  In the end, we find that a vehicle, like a car, can only turn gasoline into mechanical energy so fast.  This makes the vehicles power limited.

Were they not power limited, and instead were force limited, you could calculate that the maximum speed of a car is... infinite.  No matter what speed you were at, you could always accelerate by applying some constant amount of force.  Going back to the preface, there's no philosophical reason why this couldn't be... except that when we reach out and test our universe, our tests show that that just isn't how it works.

Comment: So suppose there is not a car but a person pulling the cart, what would be in that case? Force or power?

Comment: @PinkAura Every source of locomotion we have found has a maximum power.  At the very least, we get limited by conservation of energy, but there are plenty of other effects that show up at high power (like melting of wires or breaking of tendons)

Comment: Does that *source of locomotion* contains humans as its element?

Comment: @PinkAura Yes.  Our muscles have a maximum power.  A well trained cyclist can output about 400W max.  It's just not possible to drive the chemical equations in our muscles any harder than that.

Answer (score 0):

The flaw in OP's assumption is that the torque produced by an engine is constant. In reality, it varies with velocity (RPM). This is called a torque curve. A similar curve exists for power. Note that the throttle is assumed to be maximum in all cases. There is no reason to assume that the total load in either case is the maximum possible torque (which only occurs at a specific RPM). At constant velocity, the torque will only ever be equal to the load (comprising the resistive forces and the weight). So the realistic way to solve the question will be to find the load torque and finding the corresponding RPM (on the $x$-axis) using the torque curve.

In addition, in many cases, both the torque and power curves reach a peak and then start to decrease. The power typically reaches its peak after the torque does. So in reality, neither assumption is always correct. As such, my opinion is that the question is ill-posed unless the variation of torque with RPM is specified.

Comment: "The flaw in OP's assumption is that the torque produced by an engine is constant. " The Force F would be different for velocities $v$ and $2v$, is that what you mean?

Comment: If that's true, is it true only for car engines? Like, i cannot imagine a human behaving like that... He can probably have any force corresponding to any velocity . I think

Comment: @PinkAura Yes, the forces are different because the weight of the carts are different. The assumption is that the engine is operating at maximum throttle in all cases because if not, you will be operating *below* the torque curve and you can always increase force by increasing the throttle. So since we are on the torque curve and we have different forces, the velocities must be different.

Comment: @PinkAura Many energy sources have similar curves because there is simply a physical limit on how fast energy can be converted. The point is, (for 100% throttle) there is a fixed force and power for each RPM.

Answer (score -1):

You method requires you to change the engine in the car between the two runs.

According to you, in the first run the power of the engine is $F\,v$ and in the second run the power of the engine is $F\,2v$, ie twice as powerful.

Comment: Can't the engine change its power during the motion, according to need? I don't really understand the point you are trying to make. Can you pls elaborate more?

Comment: @PinkAura What it means is that surely engine can change its power output during motion but not the **maximum power output** because the latter depends on the quality and long term condition of the engine.

Comment: @Proscionexium :  I believe the OP's entire question comes down to:  Why do we expect the maximum power output of the engine (as opposed to, say, the maximum force it can apply) to depend on the quality and long term condition of the engine?

Comment: @WillO yes, exactly that's what i am trying to ask

Answer (score -1):

If you keep the same engine, the maximum power output remains the same. You know that power $P =F.v$ and $P_{max}=F.v_{max}$. If you keep on adding mass to your car, the gravitational force increases but since your car cannot change its maximum power output, it has to change the maximum velocity that can be attained with that mass so that the $P_{max}$ will remain same.

Comment: $F$ changes too

Comment: @PinkAura I have considered that $F$ changes while I said about gravity. Clearly you need greater force from wheels and greater power from engine to pull greater mass up.